# laravel renoki-co / befriended functionality works fine but failing in tests

Tags: laravel

I have installed the renoki-co/befriended plugin for laravel. The functionality works fine but when I test the functionality using PHPUNIT I am getting failures.

What I am testing is if a user model follows a group model

My test does the following:

```
$member = $this->signInAsUser();
$group = factory(Group::class)->create();
```

when I execute the following:

```
$member->follow($group);
```

true is returned

Now when I execute the following code:

```
abort_if(!auth()->user()->isFollowing($group), \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');
```

I get forbidden, even through the user is following the group

When I query the database the data is there showing the user following the group and executing the following code

```
auth()->user()->isFollowing($group)
```

always give me false in the test.

Wierd one
Danny

Comment: The problem might be that the `following` relationship is already loaded before the member follows the group, therefore it will be cached without the group, so you would have to use `$member->refresh();` after `$member->follow($group);`, which means that you probably have to create the user, follow the group and then login in the user, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks I will try that out Remul and let you know

Comment: A simple way to test it would be using `auth()->user()->fresh()->isFollowing($group)` in your test and see if it returns true.

Comment: That didn't seem to work Remul hmmm

Comment: Does my second comment return `true` in the test?

Comment: No it doesn't Remul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do here was add to my policy to check if the user model and group model and ids exist in the db table followers to enable this to work for tests. A double check here but that's ok.